# I am trying using %%~tf check date modified show ECHO is off

Tags: batch-file

I am trying using `%%~tf` check date modified, but it shows `ECHO is off.`

```
@echo off
SET filename1="test1.txt"
SET filename2="test2.txt"

FOR %%f IN (%filename1%) DO ( SET filedatetime1=%%~tf )
FOR %%f IN (%filename2%) DO ( SET filedatetime2=%%~tf )

SET filedate1=%filedatetime1:~0,-9%
SET filedate2=%filedatetime2:~0,-9%
echo %filedate1%
echo %filedate2%
```

Show results:

```
07/28/2020
ECHO is off.
```

Why does it show ECHO is off?

Comment: There is no file.

Comment: `ECHO is off` or `ECHO is on` is the result of a blank echo, `echo ` and that means that the variables are empty